# Is classOf[] in Scala 2.8 different from 2.7?

Tags: scala, scala-2.8, java.lang.class

I have an interface from Java

```
public class IJava
{
   ...
   public java.lang.Class getType();
   ...
}
```

It is inherited in Scala

```
class CScala
{
    def getType() = classOf[Foo]
}
```

It worked in Scala 2.7.7. But in 2.8.0.RC1, I get

```
type mismatch;  found   : java.lang.Class[Foo](classOf[Foo])  
required: java.lang.Class
```

How do I get `java.lang.Class` in Scala 2.8?

Answer (score 6):

Try to annotate the return type of `getType()` as `java.lang.Class`. The problem here is that you are using a raw type on the interface, and raw types really don't work well with Scala.

Answer (score 1):

annotate the return type java.lang.Class[Foo]

class CScala
{
    def getType() : java.lang.Class[Foo] = classOf[Foo]
}

it is ok.

But, the method signature is changed by subclass. Interesting!